# On Multiple Threads Accessing and Editing a Global Field

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I am attempting to use multithreading to simulate two users on a single bank account, withdrawing and depositing money. I'd like for the two users to act on a single shared variable, of course representing the account balance.

The actions for depositing or withdrawing money is a randomly picked- either 1 or 2 (depositing and withdrawing respectively). When depositing, I want the depositing action to take 1 second and the withdrawing action to take 0.5 seconds. In this time interval, the thread must wait for the other thread to complete an action before withdrawing/depositing itself.

My biggest problem, however, is how the two threads can each edit a single shared numeric field, the balance. The first time I tried, each thread created its own instance of balance and acted separately on them. I'd like each thread's action (withdraw/deposit) to affect the global field "balance"- not the instance field.

Thread class and Driver class I have constructed so far listed below.

**Thread creator class:**

```
public class BankAccountSim extends Thread{
public double balance = 1000;
public String threadName;

BankAccountSim(String name){
    threadName = name;
}
public void run(){
    System.out.println(threadName + "account initiated.");
    while(true){
        try{
            Random rand = new Random();
            int num = rand.nextInt(2) + 1;
            if(num == 1){
                System.out.println(threadName + " is depositing in the bank.");
                balance += 1;
                System.out.println("The new balance is " + balance + " dollars" );
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                Thread.yield();
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(threadName + " is withdrawing from the bank.");
                balance -= 1;
                System.out.println("The new balance is " + balance + " dollars.");
                Thread.sleep(500);
                Thread.yield();
                }
        }

        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Process terminated.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Thread Driver class:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.Random;

public class BankAccountSimDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args){

    Thread user1 = new BankAccountSim("user1");
    Thread user2 = new BankAccountSim("user2");

    user1.start();
    user2.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: you could make the `balance` static, and maybe even use AtomicInteger

Comment: Rather than making `BankAccountSim` extend from `Thread`, simply make it a simple class.  Create a single instance of this class and then pass that to you threads which should then perform actions upon it.  `BankAccountSim` should provide `synchronized` methods which `withdraw` or `deposit` to the account

Comment: and if you are really wanting to use this code, then Money should never be a `double`

Comment: I think this exact scenario was addressed in *Core Java Volume 1*.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a design issue. You are better off creating a bank account and share it with the clients, just like in the real world.

```
interface BankAccount {
    // Query the balance
    BigDecimal balance();

    // Make a deposit and return the new balance
    BigDecimal deposit(BigDecimal amount);

    // Make a withdrawal and return the new balance
    BigDecimal withdraw(BigDecimal amount);
}

// Implements the Runnable interface for run in another thread.
class BankClient implements Runnable {
    private final String clientName;

    private final BankAccount bankAccount;

    public BankClient(String clientName, BankAccount bankAccount) {
        this.clientName = clientName;
        this.bankAccount = bankAccount;
    }

    public void run() {
        // while(true) ...
    }
}

class SimpleBankAccount implements BankAccount {
    private BigDecimal balance = BigDecimal.ZERO;

    public SimpleBankAccount(BigDecimal initialBalance) {
        this.balance = initialBalance;
    }

    public synchronized BigDecimal balance () {
        return balance;
    }

    public synchronized BigDecimal deposit(BigDecimal amount) {
        return balance = balance.add(amount);
    }

    public synchronized BigDecimal withdraw(BigDecimal amount) {
        if (balance.compareTo(amount) < 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not enough balance.");
        }
        return balance = balance.subtract(amount);
    }
}

public class SimDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BankAccount account = new SimpleBankAccount(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000));

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new BankClient("client-1", account));
        thread t2 = new Thread(new BankClient("client-2", account));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Luke- extremely helpful but with one issue: How do I write the run() method in the BankAccount class such that I can call the synchronized deposit and withdraw methods? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting that you want one in it's own thread but, don't think of the `BankAccount` as a Thread, the Action is a Thread.  One note about this design.  My personal rule of thumb is I only use `volatile` for primitive types.  If you change `balance` to a `Double` or some other object, lock on an `Object` or use and `AtomicReference` or something.

```
public class BankAccount {
    static volatile double balance = 0;

    public void deposit(double amount) {
        class Deposit implements Runnable {
            double amount;
            Deposit(double d) { amount = d; }
            public void run() {
                balance += amount;
            }
        }
        new Thread(new Deposit(amount)).run();
    }
    public synchronized void withdraw(double amount) {
        class Withdraw implements Runnable {
            double amount;
            public Withdraw(double d) { amount = d; }
            public void run() {
                balance -= amount;
            }
        }
        new Thread(new Withdraw(amount)).run();
    }

    //
    // A little Test 
    //
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankAccount ba = new BankAccount();

        ba.deposit(34576.2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to make balance an [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) by changing:

```
public double balance = 1000;
```

**TO**

```
public AtomicInteger balance = new AtomicInteger(1000);
```

You would however need to slightly modify how you're updating the balance for example to add to it:

```
balance.addAndGet(1);
```